# Наличие в словаре ключ : значение

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Устал уже изобретать велосипед и работать со словарями вручную. Кто подскажет универсальный способ проверять наличие ключа : значения в словаре. Важно! Вложенность словаря достигает 5 уровней.

Могут быть следующие ситуации:

1. Ключ : значение существуют
2. Ключ : значение НЕ существуют
3. Ключ существует : значение пустое или None

Возвращать True только в первом случае, не выкидывать исключения.

На данный момент я проверяю обычными методами словаря, например так:

```py
if owner.get("email"):                                # Может быть или не быть
    if owner.get('email').get("value"):               # Может быть или не быть, также значение может быть None
        out["emailAddress"] = owner["email"]["value"]
        out["invoiceDeliveryType"] = 1
    else:
        out["invoiceDeliveryType"] = 2
else:
    out["invoiceDeliveryType"] = 2
```

Есть ли универсальный способ для определения, что ключ : значение существует и значение не пусто, не зависимо от уровня вложенности

Входные данные:

1 случай:

```py
{
    "data":{
        "invoice_id": 17304,
        "location_name": "live",
        "owner":{
            "email":{
                "value":"test@test.com",
                "note" : "notice"
            },
            "name":"Petruxa Stepanovich",
            "role":1,
            "phone":{
                "prefix":"+7",
                "number":"000000000"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2 случай

```py
{
    "data":{
        "invoice_id": 17304,
        "location_name": "live"
    }
}
```

3 случай

```py
{
    "data":{
        "invoice_id": 17304,
        "location_name": "live",
        "owner":{
            "email":None,
            "name":"Petruxa Stepanovich",
            "role":1,
            "phone":{
                "prefix":"+7",
                "number":"000000000"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросе воспроизводимые примеры данных для всех трех категорий (ситуаций)...

Comment: @MaxU добавлено в вопрос, соответственно перед `if`'ом в блоке кода, так же идет отбработка

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну можно немного сократить ваш код, плюс я написал функцию, достающую значение из вложенного словаря, хотя, кажется, уже были подобные вопросы и там должны быть подобные функции реализованы:

```
def safe_get(data, key_chain):
    for key in key_chain.split('/'):
        if not (data and key in data):
            return None
        data = data[key]
    return data
        
email = safe_get(data_dict, 'data/owner/email/value')
if email:
    out["emailAddress"] = email
    out["invoiceDeliveryType"] = 1
else:
    out["invoiceDeliveryType"] = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно через сторонний модуль `dpath` (`pip install dpath`) делать запрос по путям (для вашей задачи сделайте, например, функцию на основе этого модуля, что и путь проверит и значение):

```
import dpath.util

data = {
    "data": {
        "invoice_id": 17304,
        "location_name": "live",
        "owner":{
            "email":{
                "value":"test@test.com",
                "note" : "notice"
            },
            "name":"Petruxa Stepanovich",
            "role":1,
            "phone":{
                "prefix":"+7",
                "number":"000000000"
            }
        }
    }
}

print(dpath.util.get(data, 'data/owner/email/value'))
# test@test.com
```

Если в пути что-то будет отсутствовать, то будет выброшено `KeyError`, что случится для второго и третьего вариантов. Мы можем ловить `KeyError`, а для удобства сделаем функцию:

```
def has_key(data: dict, path: str) -> bool:
    try:
        dpath.util.get(data, path)
        return True
    except KeyError:
        return False
```

Проверяем:

```
data1 = {
    "data": {
        "invoice_id": 17304,
        "location_name": "live",
        "owner":{
            "email":{
                "value":"test@test.com",
                "note" : "notice"
            },
            "name":"Petruxa Stepanovich",
            "role":1,
            "phone":{
                "prefix":"+7",
                "number":"000000000"
            }
        }
    }
}

data2 = {
    "data":{
        "invoice_id": 17304,
        "location_name": "live"
    }
}

data3 = {
    "data":{
        "invoice_id": 17304,
        "location_name": "live",
        "owner":{
            "email":None,
            "name":"Petruxa Stepanovich",
            "role":1,
            "phone":{
                "prefix":"+7",
                "number":"000000000"
            }
        }
    }
}

print(has_key(data1, 'data/owner/email/value'))  # True
print(has_key(data2, 'data/owner/email/value'))  # False
print(has_key(data3, 'data/owner/email/value'))  # False
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать без библиотек через ванильную рекурсию внутри словаря.

Итерируем словарь, если нашли ключ-значение, то их возвращаем в виде `[1, (ключ, значение)]`. Если находим словарь, то уходим глубже. Если ничего не нашли, то возвращаем `[2, None]`.

Я немного добавил код. Если находит ключ `email`, а внутри у него не словарь, а строка, то также выводится `[1, (ключ, значение)]`.

```
def chekc_pair(data: dict, key: str, key_value: str):
    for k, v in data.items():
        if k == key:
            return [1, (k, v.get(key_value))] if (isinstance(v, dict) and v.get(key_value)) \
                else [1, (k, v)] if isinstance(v, str) else [2, None]
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            return chekc_pair(v, key, key_value)
    return [2, None]
```

И текст проверки:

```
data_1 = {
    "data": {
        "invoice_id": 17304,
        "location_name": "live",
        "owner":{
            "email":{
                "value":"test@test.com",
                "note" : "notice"
            },
            "name":"Petruxa Stepanovich",
            "role":1,
            "phone":{
                "prefix":"+7",
                "number":"000000000"
            }
        }
    }
}

data_2 = {
    "data":{
        "invoice_id": 17304,
        "location_name": "live"
    }
}

data_3 = {
    "data":{
        "invoice_id": 17304,
        "location_name": "live",
        "owner":{
            "email":None,
            "name":"Petruxa Stepanovich",
            "role":1,
            "phone":{
                "prefix":"+7",
                "number":"000000000"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
print(chekc_pair(data_1, 'email', 'value'))
print(chekc_pair(data_2, 'email', 'value'))
print(chekc_pair(data_3, 'email', 'value'))
print(chekc_pair(data_4, 'email', 'value'))

#[1, ('email', 'test@test.com')]
#[2, None]
#[2, None]
#[1, ('email', 'email@example.com')]
```